# TensorFlow - Tflearning error feed_dict

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am working on a classification problem in python. Fact is, I'm not good yet in TensorFlow. So I have the same problem since a long time now and I don't know how to fix it. I hope you could help me :)

This is my data :

X : 8000 pictures : 32*32px and 3 colors (rgb), so I load a matrix X.shape = (8000,32,32,3)

Y : 4 classes (1,2,3 and 4): Y. shape = (8000,1)

This is my code :

```
network = input_data(shape=[None, 32, 32, 3], name='iput')                   
# Step 1: Convolution
network = conv_2d(network, 32, 3, activation='relu')
# Step 2: Max pooling
network = max_pool_2d(network, 2)
# Step 3: Convolution again
network = conv_2d(network, 64, 3, activation='relu')
# Step 4: Convolution yet again
network = conv_2d(network, 64, 3, activation='relu')
# Step 5: Max pooling again
network = max_pool_2d(network, 2)
# Step 6: Fully-connected 512 node neural network
network = fully_connected(network, 512, activation='relu')
# Step 7: Dropout - throw away some data randomly during training to prevent over-fitting
network = dropout(network, 0.5)
# Step 8: Fully-connected neural network with 4 outputs
network = fully_connected(network, 4, activation='softmax')
# Tell tflearn how we want to train the network
network = regression(network, optimizer='adam',
                     loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                     learning_rate=0.001)
model = tflearn.DNN(network)                
model.fit(X, Y)
```

This is my erros

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 3, in
>
> model.fit(X, Y)
>
> File "/home/side/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tflearn/models/dnn.py",
>
> line 157, in fit
>
> self.targets)
>
> File "/home/side/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tflearn/utils.py",
>   line 267, in feed_dict_builder
>       feed_dict[net_inputs[i]] = x
>   IndexError: list index out of range

I have also tried to pass X as (8000,3072) Matrix
And Y as (8000,4) Matrix, for exemple :

[0 0 1 0  <-- Y[0] = 3

0 1 0 0  <-- Y[1] = 2

...]

I reuse this code : https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/blob/master/examples/images/convnet_cifar10.py , used to class cifar10 data.

Thank you for your help,

Celia

Comment: It's hard to tell since you are using a specific code base to train your classifier. Before I try to replicate the error set a break point at line 267 of utils and let me know what is the structure of input_data and X.

Comment: X is a list of matrix contains image pixel.
For exemple, X[0] contains 3 matrix (28x28)

Comment: input_data : <tf.Tensor 'InputData_3/X:0' shape=(?, 32, 32, 3) dtype=float32>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another option is to add:

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
```

As the first line of your code

Answer (score 3):

Paraphrased from the source code :

The number of inputs don't match the expected ones.
If you are using ipython notebook, make sure you didn't run the graph construction cell multiple times. Or enclose the graph construction in the `with tf.Graph().as_default()` block.

Comment: Hi ! I don't use notebook.
Could you explain more "the number of inuts don't match the expected ones" ?
My X matrix is (8000,32,32,3) and input_data is the same.
Thank you :)

Comment: Hey!... I haven't used `tflearn` before, but from [source code](https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/blob/master/tflearn/utils.py#L267) ... I have a suggestion ... can you try making `X` and `Y` as lists with single item ... as in, `X, Y = [X], [Y]`, and then call the `model.fit(X, Y)`

Answer (score 1):

As motjuste says when you use a notebooks with TFLearn, you should restart your kernel everytime you run your code.

See this issue in github:

https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/issues/360

Answer (score 0):

as Luis Leal says, its a good way to solve this problem, but after adding this code, it's wrong as follow

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'reset_default_graph'
```

so, if you have same problem too, you can use the code

```py
from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
ops.reset_default_graph()
```

replace
`tf.reset_default_graph()`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31485986)